# microcontroller resetting and hanging problem

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega

I am controlling a 16x2 LCD and a high electrical device using ATmega8l microcontroller but if there appears a spark in AC power line due to high electrical device then my microcontroller goes to reset or unreadable character on LCD or controller goes to hang and I have to reset.

please help me what should i do ?

Comment: Are you driving the devices directly from the controller pins? If they draw more than 40mA that would damage the controller, and we usually do not know how it will damage the controller. You can use a transistor like BC548 to drive high current electrical instruments.

Comment: To get a good answer you should probably add a schematic or at least block diagram of what you're controlling and how. Also details of how the Arduino is powered.

Comment: Since you mention an ATmega8L, is this actually an Arduino or is that an incorrect tag? Just checking, as current Arduino models use other AVR microcontrollers.

Comment: Please add a photograph of your setup.

Comment: Same problem I am facing, we are manufacturing pyrometers (non contact temperature measurement instrument) using microcontroller, we installed our pyrometer on Induction furnace, it is working well but occasionally some time it will be hanged and I think it will be due to external noise generated by furnace. Can you help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: @PareshPatel Please ask this as a new question. || Use the [ASK QUESTION](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) at the top of each p[age.

Comment: @PareshPatel You will need to provide MUCH more information. Circuit diagram, power supply specifications, and links to datasheets and other information. What power supply filtering do you have? Does anything else share the power supply with the pyrometer? ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the power supply for your ATmega is unable to supply enough power during those sparkling times when you turn your AC load on.  If the power to the processor drops to below a certain voltage, it will reset. You want to add a big electrolytic capacitor between the Vcc and Gnd pins: you probably have two Vcc and two Gnd pins; add a capacitor for both.

I don't know how you are controlling your AC device: is it possible that some of the line voltage is reaching your ATmega?  That would be bad.

Also as [Rick_2047](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/1200/rick-2047) notes, make sure you are not pulling more than 40mA from each one of your ATmega pins, and even 40mA is a bit much.  If you need to drive loads more than 20mA consider using transistors or FETs. If you are using a relay to switch your AC load it likely needs a decent amount of power, so use a transistor.

Finally, if you *are* using a relay, you need to snub the transient voltages generated when you turn it off. There needs to be a diode in parallel with the relay contacts to safely handle the transient voltages.

Comment: i think you mean "sparking times" not "sparkling times"

Answer (score 0):

This might possibly because of sudden change in the voltage level input to the microcontroller. The obvious solution to the problem is using a large electrolytic capacitor in parralel with the source, so that it prevents any voltage drop occurring. But again, electrolytic capacitors have their own limitations. They may be good at charge storing capacity but are poor at fast discharging. So if a sudden sharp voltage change occurs, electrolytic capacitors may not be able to discharge very fast so as to compensate for the voltage change. Hence in addition to a large electrolytic cap, you must use a ceramic cap very close to the power input to the microcontroller. These caps have lower ESR and can provide better transient response.

Most of the times it is not the low frequency voltage changes (where electrolytic capacitors are more helpful) but the high frequency voltage change that causes such problems.

My micontroller also behaved this way. After a bit of troubleshooting, I found the problem was sudden jerks in voltage level input to the microcontroller. Electrolytic capacitors helped, but ceramic ones completely solved the issue.